# QRDA: eCQM to QDM mapping, how?

Tags: hl7, ccd, hl7-cda, c-cda

I'm trying to understand how eCQM’s QDM Data Elements listed in the html provided with each eCQM map to actual QRDA Cat 1 measure entries.

For example, do all six *Medication, Discharge* listed for CMS100v5 in the QDM section actually map to six *Discharge Medication (V3) urn:hl7ii:2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.24.3.105:2016-02-01* QDRA Cat 1 entries? What if a particular EHR/EMR does not have data for all six Discharge Medication or other QDM entries listed for eCQM, can such entries be safely omitted?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Medication Discharged you highlighted in the eCQM are criteria for data elements that should be reported as entries in the QRDA Category 1.  However the section you highlighted is just the data criteria section.  To know whether or not you need all six, you'll need to look at how the Medication Discharged data criteria are applied in the population criteria section.

Hope that helps